# What's the best way to embed a Foursquare venue map in WordPress? (one for each post)

Tags: wordpress, foursquare, openstreetmap

I want to add a map in a blog which lists locations that'll be better off using the venue's map, rather than Google Maps.

**Is there already any tool which helps with this?**

So, beside the post's content, there should have a section where you can see the location of the place in Foursquare.

If this needs knowledge of API use, please point me in the right direction towards learning how to handle that.

In short: **I'm looking for a way to embed a Foursquare's venue map in a post, within a blog made using WordPress**, better if it's using a plugin, but it could be if it doesn't take much PHP knowledge (because I don't have it).

Comment: Can you please try to explain your requirements using different words? Otherwise, here a general link on embedding OSM to WP https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/CMS

Comment: @MaM I edited now. The idea is using the map that the Foursquare venue has, because of the added information it provides.

Comment: The mapdata is OSM, the mapstyle is AFAIK Mapbox, so you can find more infos at http://switch2osm.org  
Of course this doesn't include Foursquares destinations that are property of their company and not OSM.

Comment: What about something like :  http://www.4sqmap.com/examples/api/lists.html or  http://www.4sqmap.com/venues/map  (well it's Google Map based)

Comment: @birgire That's the closest thing I've seen related to what I'm looking for. Thanks for reminding me of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have several foursquare wordpress plugins, each one offering various features. There is also an article that describe some of them here: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/7-wordpress-plugins-for-foursquare-addicts-and-venues/

You'll have more options by just searching for wordpress plugin foursquare on google.

Comment: I've searched. The list you provided mostly shows plugins which aim to display personal account's information or just a specific venue's information. None of them really seemed to come close to what I'm looking for. I've googled a lot before trying on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Having a look at foursquare API, it looks like they do not offer a map for the venues, you have to use another service, they propose mapbox so you propably have to play with two APIs. That can probably be done in JavaScript client side or on the server in php, I'm afraid you will have to learn one of these or to find someone to help you :(

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo :(